# access (sql) group by query and join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables of data,

```
 Project (ID, NAME, price),
 Expenses (ID, NAME, price, PROJECT_ID,)
```

I want to find all the projects with a summary of project expenses
I tried this query , but I could not get all the projects, only what he has expenses

```
SELECT PROJECT.p_id, SUM(EXDE.EXD_AMOUNT) AS T
FROM  PROJECT 
INNER JOIN EXDE
    ON PROJECT.p_id = EXDE.P_NO
GROUP BY  PROJECT.p_id
```

I would appreciate very much any answer will help me reach a solution

Comment: Change your inner join to left outer join, and the query will do what you want.

Comment: My thanks to everyone, be successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner join selects only matches in both tables. You need Left Join.

```
SELECT PROJECT.p_id, SUM(EXDE.EXD_AMOUNT) AS T
FROM  PROJECT 
LEFT JOIN EXDE
    ON PROJECT.p_id = EXDE.P_NO
GROUP BY  PROJECT.p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT   PROJECT.p_id, SUM(EXDE.EXD_AMOUNT) AS T
  FROM   PROJECT 
             LEFT JOIN EXDE
               ON PROJECT.p_id = EXDE.P_NO
GROUP BY  PROJECT.p_id
```